# How to move images between scrollviews

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am creating an app for iOS using swiftui, but please let me know if there are any unclear points. I want to drag an image displayed in one scrollview and move it to another scrollview.My current problem is that when I drag the image to move it, once the image is out of the scrollview it doesn't show up and I can't move it to another scrollview.I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to solve this problem

thank you.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var pageOffsets: [CGSize] = Array(repeating: .zero, count: 50)
    @State private var pageGridColumns: [Int] = Array(repeating: 0, count: 50)
    let grids = Array(repeating: GridItem(.fixed(80)), count: 4)
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyVStack {
            ScrollView() {
                LazyHStack {
                    LazyVGrid(columns: grids) {
                        ForEach((1...50), id: \.self) { num in
                            Page(str: String(num))
                                .cornerRadius(8)
                                .frame(height: 60)
                                .offset(pageOffsets[num - 1])
                                .gesture(
                                    DragGesture()
                                        .onChanged { value in
                                            pageOffsets[num - 1] = value.translation
                                        }
                                        .onEnded { value in
                                            let columnIndex = Int(round(value.translation.width / 80))
                                            let newOffset = CGSize(width: CGFloat(columnIndex) * 80, height: 0)
                                            withAnimation {
                                                pageOffsets[num - 1] = newOffset
                                                pageGridColumns[num - 1] = columnIndex
                                            }
                                        }
                                )
                                .onAppear {
                                    pageGridColumns[num - 1] = (num - 1) % 4
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            ScrollView() {
                LazyHStack {
                    LazyVGrid(columns: grids) {
                        ForEach((1...50), id: \.self) { num in
                            Page(str: String(num))
                                .cornerRadius(8)
                                .frame(height: 60)
                                .offset(pageOffsets[num - 1])
                                .gesture(
                                    DragGesture()
                                        .onChanged { value in
                                            pageOffsets[num - 1] = value.translation
                                        }
                                        .onEnded { value in
                                            let columnIndex = Int(round(value.translation.width / 80))
                                            let newOffset = CGSize(width: CGFloat(columnIndex) * 80, height: 0)
                                            withAnimation {
                                                pageOffsets[num - 1] = newOffset
                                                pageGridColumns[num - 1] = columnIndex
                                            }
                                        }
                                )
                                .onAppear {
                                    pageGridColumns[num - 1] = (num - 1) % 4
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Page: View {
    let colors: [Color] = [.green, .blue, .pink, .orange, .purple]
    let str: String

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            colors.randomElement()
            Text(str)
                .font(.title)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
    }
}
```